Problem creating Gmail filter combining FROM and To fields with OR
I'd like to create a filter that moves any messages based on the From field or the To field.
In the search dialog when I populate 'From' with x OR y and 'To' with z the search created in the filter has an implied 'AND' between the 'From' and 'To' fields:
from:(x OR y) to:z

but I want the filter's search to be:
from:(x OR y) OR to:z

How can I do that?

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

'Has the words' Field
In Gmail, any search that can't be represented using the text entry boxes for the remaining fields, will be placed in the field Has the words instead.
You can actually place your search there yourself, or simply create the filter by starting from a standard search using Gmail's Search box and then clicking the Show search options button where the search will be auto-populated in the appropriate field(s).
Any of the following search strings will work based on the example from your question:



  Option
  Variation                                                                                                




  {From:x From:y To:z}
  {From:({x y}) To:z}


  From:x OR From:y OR To:z
  From:(x OR y) OR To:z


  From:x || from:y || To:z
  From:(x || y) || To:z



Option A  -  Start Filter using Search

After populating the Search box, click the Show search options button
  
In the prepopulated Search dialog box that opens, click Create filter
  
Proceed with the remaining filter options in the next dialog box. then click Create filter:
  

Option B  -  Edit Existing Filter

In Gmail, navigate to Settings > Filters and Blocked Addresses Direct link: mail.google.com/mail#settings/filters
Scroll to your rule and click Edit
  
Delete the existing From: and To: entries and populate the Has the words field with the proper search then click Continue:
 
Modify other filter options as needed, then click Update filter:



absolutely amazing answer, thanks a lot!
It opened a whole lot of new conditional options.
I did read about 'has the words', unfortunately i didn't understand it right so i skipped it...
Many thanks!
